# JS - filter array of objects by array of property values and return array of filtered objects

Tags: arrays, filter, find, javascript-objects

I am trying (in js or jquery) to filter array of objects and return array of objects that have particular property name.

I tried `filter` and `find` functions like this:

```
var objs = [{ a:1, }, {a:2}, {a:3}, {a:4}]
var vals = [1, 2]

  function callback(obj) {
        var arr = arr || []
        console.log(arr)
        $.each(vals, function(key, val) {
            if ( val == obj.a ) {
                arr.push(obj)
            }
        })
    }

    var result = objs.find(callback);

    console.log(">>>", result)
```

Expected result is:

```
result = [{a:1}, {a:2}]
```

However it doesnt work because each iteration of `find` starts over and defines `arr` all over again.

I could ofcourse make is with two nested `$.each()` - one to iterate through array  of objects and second to iterate through array of property values but i consider is as last option - looking for something more elegant, shorter. Do you guys have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a `filter` and `indexOf`.

```js
var objs = [{ a:1, }, {a:2}, {a:3}, {a:4}]
var vals = [1, 2]


function filterByValue(source, allowedValues) {
  // Return the result of the filter.
  return source.filter(item => {
    // Returns true when `a` is present in vals (index > -1); otherwise it returns false.
    return allowedValues.indexOf(item.a) > -1;
  });
}

const
  filteredArray = filterByValue(objs, vals);

console.log(filteredArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thijs's answer works, but will get unperformant as the `vals` array gets large. To get O(n) complexity, you could build a set out of the `allowedValues` array:

```js
var objs = [{ a:1, }, {a:2}, {a:3}, {a:4}]
var vals = [1, 2]

function filterByValue(source, allowedValues) {

    allowedValues = new Set(allowedValues)
    // Return the result of the filter.

    return source.filter(item => {
    // Returns true when `a` is present in vals, otherwise it returns false.
       return allowedValues.has(item.a);
    });
}
const filteredArray = filterByValue(objs, vals);

console.log(filteredArray)
```