# Split JSON array based on the type of suggestion it's receiving

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

So I have the following JSON array

```
[
  {
    "characterID": 0,
    "description": "Series 1",
    "id": 1,
    "seriesID": 0,
    "status": "ACCEPTED",
    "type": "SERIES",
    "userID": 1
  },
  {
    "characterID": 0,
    "description": "Series 2",
    "id": 2,
    "seriesID": 0,
    "status": "ACCEPTED",
    "type": "SERIES",
    "userID": 1
  },
  {
    "characterID": 0,
    "description": "Character 1",
    "id": 1,
    "seriesID": 25,
    "status": "ACCEPTED",
    "type": "CHARACTER",
    "userID": 1
  },
  {
    "URL": "https://previews.123rf.com/images/aquir/aquir1311/aquir131100316/23569861-sample-grunge-red-round-stamp.jpg",
    "characterID": 853,
    "description": "Picture 1",
    "id": 1,
    "seriesID": 25,
    "status": "ACCEPTED",
    "type": "IMAGE",
    "userID": 1
  },
  {
    "URL": "https://c.tenor.com/uEjQxCwAWfgAAAAC/sample.gif",
    "characterID": 1,
    "description": "Gif 1",
    "id": 1,
    "seriesID": 1,
    "status": "ACCEPTED",
    "type": "GIF",
    "userID": 1
  },
  {
    "characterID": 0,
    "description": "Idea 1",
    "id": 1,
    "seriesID": 0,
    "status": "ACCEPTED",
    "type": "IDEA",
    "userID": 1
  }
]
```

However I want to achieve splitting the arrays as follows

```
[
  {
    "characterID": 0,
    "description": "Series 1",
    "id": 1,
    "seriesID": 0,
    "status": "ACCEPTED",
    "type": "SERIES",
    "userID": 1
  },
  {
    "characterID": 0,
    "description": "Series 2",
    "id": 2,
    "seriesID": 0,
    "status": "ACCEPTED",
    "type": "SERIES",
    "userID": 1
  }
]
```

```
[

  {
    "characterID": 0,
    "description": "Character 1",
    "id": 1,
    "seriesID": 25,
    "status": "ACCEPTED",
    "type": "CHARACTER",
    "userID": 1
  }
]
```

What I want to achieve is split the JSON in segments based on what `type` it contains within the array.

I am working in Javascript / Vue, if there's any solutions for this, would be appreciated.

Comment: I would JSON.parse the whole thing, run through the array allocating to separate arrays based on type, then stringify those separate results.

Comment: After the parsing, use `.filter` to extract out what you need. You can do it multiple times to get different data. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46085449/js-filter-array-of-objects-by-array-of-property-values-and-return-array-of-fil might help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Array.reduce, will work nicely here.

Below is an example.

```js
var data = JSON.parse('[{"characterID":0,"description":"Series 1","id":1,"seriesID":0,"status":"ACCEPTED","type":"SERIES","userID":1},{"characterID":0,"description":"Series 2","id":2,"seriesID":0,"status":"ACCEPTED","type":"SERIES","userID":1},{"characterID":0,"description":"Character 1","id":1,"seriesID":25,"status":"ACCEPTED","type":"CHARACTER","userID":1},{"URL":"https://previews.123rf.com/images/aquir/aquir1311/aquir131100316/23569861-sample-grunge-red-round-stamp.jpg","characterID":853,"description":"Picture 1","id":1,"seriesID":25,"status":"ACCEPTED","type":"IMAGE","userID":1},{"URL":"https://c.tenor.com/uEjQxCwAWfgAAAAC/sample.gif","characterID":1,"description":"Gif 1","id":1,"seriesID":1,"status":"ACCEPTED","type":"GIF","userID":1},{"characterID":0,"description":"Idea 1","id":1,"seriesID":0,"status":"ACCEPTED","type":"IDEA","userID":1}]');


const grouped = data.reduce((a, v) => {
  if (!a[v.type]) a[v.type] = [];
  a[v.type].push(v);
  return a;
}, {});

console.log(grouped);
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is using a utility library like [lodash](https://lodash.com/)
Specifically method [groupBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#groupBy)

```
_.groupBy(data, 'type');// {SERIES: Array(2), CHARACTER: Array(1), IMAGE: Array(1), GIF: Array(1), IDEA: Array(1)}
```

***UPDATE:(vanilla approach without any libraries)***
Solution Using The ***`Map`*** which is object holds *key-value pairs* ***key is the type*** and ***value is their entry group of that type*** with [?. Optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) and [?? Nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)

```js
let map = new Map()
for(entry of data){
    const type = entry?.type ?? "untyped";
    map.set(type, [...map.get(type)??[],entry])
}
// Map(5) {'SERIES' => Array(2), 'CHARACTER' => Array(1), 'IMAGE' => Array(1), 'GIF' => Array(1), 'IDEA' => Array(1)}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use reduce to create a new object with type as keys:

```
var res = data.reduce((acc, val) => {
if (!acc[val.type]) {
    acc[val.type] = [val];
} else {
    acc[val.type].push(val)
}
return acc;

}, {})
```

The result will look something like:

```
{
   "SERIES":[
      {
         "characterID":0,
         "description":"Series 1",
         "id":1,
         "seriesID":0,
         "status":"ACCEPTED",
         "type":"SERIES",
         "userID":1
      },
      {
         "characterID":0,
         "description":"Series 2",
         "id":2,
         "seriesID":0,
         "status":"ACCEPTED",
         "type":"SERIES",
         "userID":1
      }
   ],
   "CHARACTER":[
      {
         "characterID":0,
         "description":"Character 1",
         "id":1,
         "seriesID":25,
         "status":"ACCEPTED",
         "type":"CHARACTER",
         "userID":1
      }
   ],
   "IMAGE":[
      {
         "URL":"https://previews.123rf.com/images/aquir/aquir1311/aquir131100316/23569861-sample-grunge-red-round-stamp.jpg",
         "characterID":853,
         "description":"Picture 1",
         "id":1,
         "seriesID":25,
         "status":"ACCEPTED",
         "type":"IMAGE",
         "userID":1
      }
   ],
   "GIF":[
      {
         "URL":"https://c.tenor.com/uEjQxCwAWfgAAAAC/sample.gif",
         "characterID":1,
         "description":"Gif 1",
         "id":1,
         "seriesID":1,
         "status":"ACCEPTED",
         "type":"GIF",
         "userID":1
      }
   ],
   "IDEA":[
      {
         "characterID":0,
         "description":"Idea 1",
         "id":1,
         "seriesID":0,
         "status":"ACCEPTED",
         "type":"IDEA",
         "userID":1
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you want to split and store into separate arrays or not but, if thats the case you can try this:

```js
const obj = [
  {
    "characterID": 0,
    "description": "Series 1",
    "id": 1,
    "seriesID": 0,
    "status": "ACCEPTED",
    "type": "SERIES",
    "userID": 1
  },
  {
    "characterID": 0,
    "description": "Series 2",
    "id": 2,
    "seriesID": 0,
    "status": "ACCEPTED",
    "type": "SERIES",
    "userID": 1
  },
  {
    "characterID": 0,
    "description": "Character 1",
    "id": 1,
    "seriesID": 25,
    "status": "ACCEPTED",
    "type": "CHARACTER",
    "userID": 1
  },
  {
    "URL": "https://previews.123rf.com/images/aquir/aquir1311/aquir131100316/23569861-sample-grunge-red-round-stamp.jpg",
    "characterID": 853,
    "description": "Picture 1",
    "id": 1,
    "seriesID": 25,
    "status": "ACCEPTED",
    "type": "IMAGE",
    "userID": 1
  },
  {
    "URL": "https://c.tenor.com/uEjQxCwAWfgAAAAC/sample.gif",
    "characterID": 1,
    "description": "Gif 1",
    "id": 1,
    "seriesID": 1,
    "status": "ACCEPTED",
    "type": "GIF",
    "userID": 1
  },
  {
    "characterID": 0,
    "description": "Idea 1",
    "id": 1,
    "seriesID": 0,
    "status": "ACCEPTED",
    "type": "IDEA",
    "userID": 1
  }
];

const seriesTypeObjs = [];

obj.map(eachObj => {
  if (eachObj.type === 'SERIES'){
    seriesTypeObjs.push(eachObj);
  }
});
console.log('Series Type Objs =>', seriesTypeObjs);
```

You can use the same code to test for other `type` values too.